# Could only an index of a multidimensional array returning a value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

See the example below to understand the idea:

```
$arr = array
(
    0 => array (
        $this => 3,   // instead 0 => 3,
        'name' => 'three',
    ),
    1 => array (
        $this => 5,   // instead 0 => 5,
        'name' => 'five',
    ),
    2 => array (
        $this => 7,   // instead 0 => 7,
        'name' => 'seven',
    ),
);
```

For each index have an bidimensional array. However instead to call for $arr[0][0], turn possible call for $arr[0]. These are imaginaries echoes with the wanted result.

```
echo $arr[0];           // printing 3
echo $arr[0]['name'];   // printing 'three'
echo $arr[0][0];        // printing 3 (not relevant)
```

There are something like that?

Comment: this makes very little sense

Comment: there is something like that but what's the question again?

Comment: well i still have no idea what you are asking

Comment: Array to string conversion did you get while echoing array value

Comment: You have array keys called `$this` - normally that variable is used to represent the current object. Is that what you intended?

Comment: I think he wants to be able to call the first level array key so it returns the value of the second levels first array key or somehing. Kinda hard to explain. Kinda like: `$arr[0]` returns value of `$arr[0][0]`

Comment: Don't. `$this` should represent the index `$arr[$i][0]`

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? There is way to achieve this thing in PHP 5, I think.

Comment: Best solution I could come up with was to use [reset()](http://php.net/reset). This puts the arrays pointer to the first available element. In your case `$arr[0]` is simply another array. So to make it return the value of the first element in that array, simply do `echo reset($arr[0]);`

Comment: Thank you @icecub, simple solution, many possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5, you can extend the ArrayObject to make it array-like object. You can override some of its behavior

```
class SillyArray extends ArrayObject {
    public function __construct($a)
    {
        foreach($a as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $a[$key] = new SillyArray($value);
            }
        }

        parent::__construct($a);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        $result = parent::offsetGet(0);

        if (isset($result)) {
            return (string)$result;
        }

        return "";
    }
}

$a = new SillyArray(
    array(0 => array(
        0 => 3,
        'name' => 'there'
    ))
);

echo $a[0];
echo $a[0][0];
echo $a[0]['name'];
```

Comment: It took me a moment to find, but this might be an addition to your answer: `echo reset($arr[0]);` That will return the value of the second levels first key.

Comment: @icecub, found solution now. With combination of magic function and ArrayObject.

Comment: Amazing! Tested it and works like a charm! +1

Comment: Yes, I was looking it and trying to display the 'name' before he edit the answer, but crazy things happened :D Smart ideia like magic.

Comment: how very convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are trying to access elements of Multidimensional Arrays

```
<?php
         $marks = array( 
            "m" => array
            (
               "physics" => 35,
               "maths" => 30,   
               "chemistry" => 39
            ),

            "q" => array
            (
               "physics" => 30,
               "maths" => 32,
               "chemistry" => 29
            ),

            "z" => array
            (
               "physics" => 31,
               "maths" => 22,
               "chemistry" => 39
            )
         );

         /* Accessing multi-dimensional array values */
         echo "Marks for m in physics : " ;
         echo $marks['m']['physics'] . "<br />"; 

         echo "Marks for q in maths : ";
         echo $marks['q']['maths'] . "<br />"; 

         echo "Marks for z in chemistry : " ;
         echo $marks['z']['chemistry'] . "<br />"; 
      ?>
```

This will produce

```
Marks for m in physics : 35
Marks for q in maths : 32
Marks for z in chemistry : 39
```

https://3v4l.org/bpL4i

now your question is returning value of $arr[0][0] by calling $arr[0] as @icecub say's then this can done by

The reset() function used to move the array's internal pointer to the first element.[LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

https://3v4l.org/Ide2L implementation

Comment: The question is how to return the value of `$arr[0][0]` by calling `$arr[0]` and you're explaining him how multidimensional arrays work..

Comment: @icecub i got it now.Thnks for pointing out mistake i will edit it.

Comment: Well I'll remove the downvote cuz at least you're trying. But please, make sure to give an answer that makes sense or simply remove it ;)